# Node Package Manager test case issue

Tags: node.js, npm

I am getting the below error while running the npm command from "c:\project" folder

```
nyc --reporter=lcov mocha

internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985
  throw err;
  ^
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\project\node'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:982:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:864:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:18:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
```

My nodejs version is 12.16.1 "C:\project" has package.json and node_modules.

Any suggestions to solve this issue will be helpful

Comment: Try running the command without npm: `npx nyc --reporter=lcov mocha`.

Comment: if I run the command mocha, I am able to run test cases. I am getting error if I try to run "nyc mocha"

Answer (score 1):

Seems like issue with nyc version. Upgraded nyc to latest (15.0.0) and that solved the issue